# A function of encapsulation is not work in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I want to encapsulate a function, it can be called directly, make it's object (For example: $('.box')) can be dragging.

this is my code:

```js
$.fn.drag = function() {
  var movebox = $(this);
  movebox.onmousedown = function() {
    var moveX = event.clientX,
      moveY = event.clientY,
      ofX = movebox.offsetLeft,
      ofY = movebox.offsetTop,
      newmovX = moveX - ofX,
      newmovY = moveY - ofY;
    document.onmousemove = function() {
      var moveX = event.clientX,
        moveX_1 = event.clientX - newmovX,
        moveY_1 = event.clientY - newmovY;
      movebox.style.top = moveY_1 + "px";
      movebox.style.left = moveX_1 + "px";
    };
    document.onmouseup = function() {
      document.onmousemove = function() {};
      document.onmouseup = function() {};
    }
  }
}
$(".box").drag();
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

question:
   When I use it, it doesn't work, and it doesn't enter the 'onmousedown' function.why? I'm a new user who can help me to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Firstly, please include the *actual* code in the question, not a picture of it. Secondly, what precisely is not working? We need to know what it is doing, and what you expect it to be doing.

Comment: wait i will also post a code image....;)

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  thank you for your advice

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: You are useing jQuery and mixing it with native DOM events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that when you use JQuery to initializethe var movebox, you must use jquery to get and set his property:

- movebox.onmousedown ----> movebox.mousedown(function(event)
- movebox.offsetLeft ----> movebox.offset().left

To move the box, you must set the offset but not the top css style of the box : `movebox.offset({top: moveX_1, left: moveY_1});

The result is on the code snippet, you have to improve it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.drag = function(){
        var movebox = $(this);
        movebox.bind('mousedown.drag',function(event){
            var moveX = event.clientX;
            var moveY = event.clientY;
            var ofX = movebox.offset().left;
            var ofY = movebox.offset().top;
            var newmovX = moveX - ofX;
            var newmovY = moveX - ofY;
            $('body').bind('mousemove.drag', function(event){
                var moveX = event.clientX;
                var moveX_1 = event.clientX - newmovX;
                var moveY_1 = event.clientY - newmovY;
                movebox.offset({top: moveX_1, left: moveY_1});
            });
            $('body').bind('mouseup.drag',function(){
                //document.onmousemove = function(){};
                //document.onmouseup = function(){};
                $(document).unbind('mousemove.drag mouseup.drag');
            });
        });
    };
    $.fn.undrag = function(){
        $(this).unbind('mousedown.drag');
    }
    $(".box").drag();
});
```

```css
            .box {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                top: 100px;
                background-color: yellow;
              }
```

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The code</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <body>
    <div class="box">
        
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

pass the event variable to the handlers.

```
movebox.onmousedown = function(event){
document.onmousemove=function(event){
document.onmouseup=function(event){
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the JavaScriupt console in your browser. I am sure it has plenty of error messages for you to read. You are mixing jQuery and Native DOM. You do not defined `event` anywhere.

```
var movebox = $(this);  >//jquery object
movebox.onmousedown = function() {  <--jquery does not have onmousedown
```

jQuery has `mousedown`

```
movebox.on("mousedown", function (event) {
    //your code here
});
```

Other issue you will have is if you bind something again, the second one will blow up your first instance since you are binding over the document events.

Comment: yes, I'm new jser, so sometimes I mixing it~thank you